# Get total number of rows when using LIMIT

Tags: php, mysql

Been following examples from [here](http://www.arraystudio.com/as-workshop/mysql-get-total-number-of-rows-when-using-limit.html) and many other sites but not getting the expected results

Snippet of my PHP code;

```
$query="SELECT * FROM book";
$result=mysql_query($query);
echo mysql_num_rows($result); //returns 14


$query="SELECT FOUND_ROWS()";
$rtotal=mysql_query($query);
echo mysql_result($rtotal,0); //returns 14


$query="SELECT * FROM book LIMIT 0,4";
$result=mysql_query($query);
echo mysql_num_rows($result); //returns 4


$query="SELECT FOUND_ROWS()";
$rtotal=mysql_query($query);
echo mysql_result($rtotal,0); //returns 4 Why is it 4 and not 14??
```

In the last example why is it 4 and not 14?? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add a SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS to your select statement: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

This forces MySQL to count the rows as if the limit statement is not present.

```
$query="SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM book LIMIT 0,4";
```

Comment: Note that this should be added to the third query.

Comment: thanks!! and this was even mentioned in the blog i read, somehow i missed it completely

Answer (score 2):

Your most recent query returned 4 rows (`$query="SELECT * FROM book LIMIT 0,4";`).

That's why it returns 4 and not 14.

---

To quote the documentation:

> In the absence of the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option in the most recent successful SELECT statement, FOUND_ROWS() returns the number of rows in the result set returned by that statement. If the statement includes a LIMIT clause, FOUND_ROWS() returns the number of rows up to the limit.

Comment: Wrong. FOUND_ROWS returns the number of rows that would have been returned by the previous query if no limit was set. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Comment: @alexn: It's not wrong, see the documentation (quoted above). But to make it work as expected, `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` needs to be added.

Comment: Now that you've edited your answer it is correct. You stated that it did not work since he used a limit in the previous query. I remove my downvote if your answer becomes edited.