# Limit fetch results by page

Tags: php, mysql

this file is included in my index file, i want not more than 5 posts on page and under posts 1 2 3 4... and etc. (links to the next pages) and that it look like this index.php?page=2
Sorry for my bad grammar.

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['post_edit'])) {
    $p_id = $_GET['post_edit'];

    $p_query = mysql_query("SELECT title, post FROM posts WHERE id='$p_id'");
    $p_array = mysql_fetch_array($p_query);
    $title = $p_array['title'];
    $post = $p_array['post'];
    }
    ?>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['edit'])){
        $title_edit = $_POST['titleedit'];
        $post_edit = $_POST['postedit'];

    if(empty($title) or empty($post)){
        echo "<p>Fields empty!</p>";
        } else {
        mysql_query("UPDATE posts SET title='$title_edit', post='$post_edit' WHERE id='$p_id'");
        echo "Edit succesful!</br>";
        header('location: index.php');
    }
    }
    ?>

    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['post_edit']) && !empty($_GET['post_edit'])){
    include 'edit_post.php';
    } else {

    ?>
    <?php

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){


    echo "<div class='poststitle'>";
        echo "<div style='font-weight: bold;'>";
            echo $row['title'];
        echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";

    echo "<div class='posts'>";
        echo $row['post'];
        echo "</br>";
        echo "<hr>";

        $user_name = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = '".$row['user']."' ");
        $user_name_array = mysql_fetch_array($user_name);
            $post_id = $row['id'];

        echo "Posted by: <b>";
        echo $user_name_array['username'];
        echo "</b> | ";

        echo "Views: <b>";
        echo $row['views'];
        echo "</b> | ";

        echo "Posted on: ";
        echo "<b>";
        echo $row['date'];
        echo "</b><hr>";

    echo '</div>';

    if (loggedin()){
    if($user_level == 1){
        echo "<div class='postoptions'>";
        echo "<a href='index.php?post_edit=$post_id'><img src='img/optionicons/edit.png' width='15' height='15' alt='edit' /></a>";
        echo "<a href='del_post.php?del=$post_id'><img src='img/optionicons/cancel.png' width='15' height='15' alt='Delete' /></a>";
        echo "</div>";
        } else {
        echo "";
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you looking for php pagination script?

Comment: It's called "pagination" and there are three gajillion tutorials for it out there last time I counted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917775/truncate-number-of-pages-in-pagination

Comment: @deceze U took the time to count them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT N, M

Where N - number of limited rows and M(offset) = N * (PAGE -1)

Comment: got it tnq. but now how do i get all other results be shown on next page like this - index.php?page=2 should i make another isset? and what i need to write in it?

Comment: По Русски думаю поимеш - я хочю чтобы под постами были линки, со страницами, которые автоматом бы добавлялись когда привышается лимит записей на одной странице, как только лемит привышен, чтоб происходил перенос на следующую страциу в виде ?page=2 и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `LIMIT` clause in your MySQL query, see [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

in order to calculate the numbe rof pages, you also need the total number of rows, this can be found using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`, see [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084029/mysql-get-total-number-of-rows-when-using-limit)